# PHP regex backreference not working

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a regex pattern which works perfectly when I test it in Regexr, but when I use it in my PHP code it doesn't always match when it should match.

[The regular expression](http://www.regexr.com/39hom), including some examples that should and shouldn't match.

Example PHP code that should match but doesn't:

```
preg_match('/^([~]{3,})\s*([\w-]+)?\s*(?:\{([\w-\s]+)\})?\s*(\2[\w-]+)?\s*$/', "~~~ {class} lang", $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);
```

I believe the problem is caused by the backreference in the last capture group `(\2[\w-]+)`, however, I can't quire figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're referring to a non-existing group(group 2). So remove `\2` from the regex.

```
^([~]{3,})\s*([\w-]+)?\s*(?:\{([-\w\s]+)\})?\s*([\w-]+)?\s*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iQ1eD9/2)

```
    ~~~  {class} lang
     |  |   |      |
  Group1| Group3 Group4
        |
Missing group 2
```

Comment: I like, how you illustrate it :)

Comment: Thanks, you and @hwnd helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by capturing group `#2`, you have made this group optional. So since it may or may not exist, you need to make your backreference optional as well or else it always looks for a required group.

However, since all groups are optional I would just recurse the subpattern of the second group.

```
^(~{3,})\s*([\w-]+)?\s*(?:{([^}]+)})?\s*((?2))?\s*$
```

Example:

```
$str = '~~~ {class} lang';
preg_match('/^(~{3,})\s*([\w-]+)?\s*(?:{([^}]+)})?\s*((?2))?\s*$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(16) "~~~ {class} lang"
  [1]=> string(3) "~~~"
  [2]=> string(0) ""                   # Returns "" for optional groups that dont exist
  [3]=> string(5) "class"
  [4]=> string(4) "lang"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this way '~~~ lang {class} lang' gives a match as well, and it shouldn't.

Comment: I just solved it my changing the 2nd capturing group to `([\w-]*)`, making it an empty string when it's not there instead of non-existent.

Comment: Tell me what it should exactly match and I'll take a look when I get back home

Comment: I've already fixed the problem thanks to your help. I've posted an answer myself explaining everything :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers below helped me figure out why it wasn't working. However both the answers would give a positive match for `$str = '~~~ lang {class} lang';` which I didn't want. 
I fixed it my changing capturing group 2 to `([\w-]*)` so that even if there is no string at that place, the capturing group exists but remains empty. This way all of the following strings match:

```
$str = '~~~   lang      {no-lines float left}   ';
$str = '~~~     {class}   ';
$str = '~~~ lang';
$str = '~~~ {class } lang ';
$str = '~~~';
$str = '~~~lang{class}';
```

But this one won't:

```
$str = '~~~ css {class} php';
```

Full solution:

```
$str = '~~~ {class} lang';
preg_match('/^([~]{3,})\s*([\w-]*)?\s*(?:\{([\w-\s]+)\})?\s*(\2[\w-]+)?\s*$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```